# Which is correct usage? "...in connection with/to the crime."

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality

Which is correct?  Jones was arrested in connection **with** the crime.  or  Jones was arrested in connection **to** the crime.

Answer (score 2):

People are arrested, questioned, consulted, advised, etc, in connection **with** something.

> in connection with sth
>   ​
>   on the subject of something:
>
> They want to talk to you in connection with an unpaid tax bill.

[Connection](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/connection)